# How to redirect to a new route in Nextjs13 after returning NextResponse

Tags: redirect, routes, navigation, next.js13, app-router

After successfully registering at `app/register/page.jsx` and I want to redirect the newly registered to `app/profile/page.jsx`

I try to pass use the **redirect** inthe try block

```
    await connectMongoDB();
    const newServiceProvider = await ServiceProvider.create({ email, phone, password, services });
    if (newServiceProvider) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        message: 'A successful registration',
        success: true,
      });
    }
    redirect('/profile', push)
```

It only prints the message but dont *redirect()*